# Showing that equivalence class of path connected points is closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, equivalence-relations, connectedness, path-connected

> Let $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} $ be open and $$[x]_{\sim} = \{y \in X \mid \text{there exists 
> a continuous path from }x \text{ to }y \text{ in X}\}.$$ I want to show that $[x]_{\sim}$ is closed in/wrt. $X$.

**My attempt:**

Suppose for the sake of contradiction there existed a sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \subseteq [x]_{\sim}$
s.t. $x_{n} \to x^{*} \not\in [x]_{\sim}$. Consider now the function
\begin{align*}
f\colon [0, 1] \to X, \quad f(t) = \begin{cases}
  x^{*}, & t = 0
  \\
  l_{n}(m_{n}(t)), & t \in \left[\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n-1}\right]
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
  &l_{n}(t) = t \cdot x_{n} + (1 - t)\cdot x_{n-1}\quad \quad  \text{(line segment joining }x_{n} \text{ and }x_{n-1})
  \\[5pt] 
  &m_{n}(t) = \left(t - \frac{1}{n}\right) \cdot (n^{2} - n) \quad \quad  \text{(naturally map }
  [1 / n, 1 / (n-1)] \text{ to } [0, 1])
.\end{align*}
Since $x_{1}\in [x]_{\sim}$ there exists a continous path from $x$ to $x_{1}$ which can be joined with the continous
path $f$ from $x_{1}$ to $x^{*}$. However, this means that $x^{*} \in [x]_{\sim}$, a contradiction!

Firstly, does my attempt look correct? Secondly, what would be other ways to prove the above?

Comment: The easiest proof I know is by showing that the complement is open. Any point $x$ in the complement belongs to a different component. Since $X$ is open there is a ball around $x$, and clearly all the points in the ball can be connected to $x$ by a straight line. Conclude.

Comment: @Crostul this sounds way more concise. Is my solution still correct?

Comment: Your proof is not entirely correct: In general, the line segment between $x_n$ and $x_{n-1}$ will not be a valid path in $X$ (it may partly be outside of $X$). However, you can easily rectify this by taking a continuous path in $X$ from $x_{n-1}$ to $x_n$ which exists since $x_{n-1},x_n\in [x]$.

Comment: @msgcas Actually my proof is still not correct, even with your rectification. The problem is that we don't know how the paths connecting $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ look like. They could first go far away from $x^*$. I only define a function which satisfies $f(x_n) \to f(x^*)$ for one specific sequence, but not necessarily for all.

Comment: I agree, it still doesn't work. It seems that Crostul's solution is really the way to go.

Comment: One sign that your proof may not be correct is that it never uses that $X$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$. Of course, it could still be true without that condition. A good "potential counterexample" for such cases is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve. In your case, it gives an example of the problem you described yourself. where you can certainly find a sequence of points on the curve the tend to $(0,0)$, but you cannot make a continuous function that "ends" in $(0,0)$. Openness of $X$ helps with that, as it makes it clear you can have a line segement at the "very end".

Answer (score 1):

I assume that we are working in the Topology of the subset $A$:

if $[x]_∼ =A$ we are done.
Suppose for the sake of contradiction exists $y\in A\backslash [x]_∼$ such that
$B(y,1/n)\cap [x]_∼\neq \emptyset\;\; \forall n\in\mathbb N\;\;$ i.e $\;\;A\backslash[x]_∼$ isn't open. Hence exists $\{x_n\}\subset [x]_∼ $
which converge to $y$. Since $A$ is open, for $n_0$ big enough $B(y,1/n)\subset A, \forall n\geq n_0$. So the function:
$$f:[0,1]\rightarrow B(y,1/n_0)\subset A\;\;\; \text{such that }\; f(t)=
 (1-t)x_{n_0}+ty$$
is well-defined and continuous in $A$. So the function we are looking for is the
juxtaposition of the continuous function that connects $x$ to $x_0$ with $f$.
(hence $y$ stay in $[x]_∼$ and this is a contradiction, so $A\backslash[x]_∼$ is open i.e. $[x]_∼$ is closed)